# Is this family of minimal tori compact?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds, minimal-surfaces, torus

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth $2$-sphere and let $M = \Sigma \times \mathbb{S}^1$. Fix an integer $n \geq 0$. Is there generic set $\mathcal{S}$ of Riemannian metrics on $\Sigma$ such that the following assertion is true?

> There is a simple closed geodesic $C \subset (\Sigma,g)$, $g \in \mathcal{S}$, such that the family $\mathcal{F}_n(g)$, which consists of all embedded minimal tori in $M$ whose intersection with the (totally geodesic) torus $T = C \times \mathbb{S}^1$ has exactly $n$ connected components, is compact with respect to smooth convergence.

I suspect this is true, but I couldn't find a proof.

**Remark:** It would suffice to find a uniform *area* bound for the elements of $\mathcal{F}_n(g)$.